# Compare Dataframe field with Json

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

My dataframe is of schema

```
|-- segment: string (nullable = true)
 |-- jsonString: string (nullable = true)
```

segment column has data like

```
( (segmentationStrategyId=999, segmentID = 55) || (segmentationStrategyId=1000, segmentID = 58) )
```

ie, string

and jsonString has data of type

```
{"segment":{"999":"50","154":"342"}}
```

where first `key(999)` is `segmentationStrategyId` and its value ie`(50)` is `segmentID`
now all I want to do is check if the `segment` expression string matches to the value in `jsonString`

Any Idea how can this be done ?

Comment: make the expresssion as json string or convert the json string to expression string and compare two columns.

Comment: I guess this question is also answered in https://stackoverflow.com/a/48974181/5880706