# Apply filter condition on dataframe created from JSON

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am working on the dataframe created by JSON and then I want to apply the filter condition over the dataframe.

```
val jsonStr = """{ "metadata": [{ "key": 84896, "value": 54 },{ "key": 1234, "value": 12 }]}"""
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(jsonStr))
val df = sqlContext.read.json(rdd)
```

schema of df

```
root
 |-- metadata: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- key: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- value: long (nullable = true)
```

now I need to filter the dataframe which I am trying to do as

```
val df1=df.where("key == 84896")
```

which throws error

```
ERROR Executor - Exception in task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1)
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`key`' given input columns: [metadata]; line 1 pos 0;
'Filter ('key = 84896)
```

The reason I want to use where clause is because of the expression string which I want to use directly 
eg `( (key == 999, value == 55) || (key == 1234, value == 12) )`

Comment: Are you saying that you want to convert the above array column to `( (key == 999, value == 55) || (key == 1234, value == 12) )` like string?

Comment: @RameshMaharjan no, what I want to do is basically `df1=df.where("( (key == 999, value == 55) || (key == 1234, value == 12) )")`

Comment: I have answered below, please have a look :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**From what I have understood from your question and comment is that you are trying to apply `( (key == 999, value == 55) || (key == 1234, value == 12) )` expression to filter the dataframe rows.**

First of all, the expression needs changes as it cannot be applied as expression to `dataframe` in *spark* so you need to change as

```
val expression = """( (key == 999, value == 55) || (key == 1234, value == 12) )"""
val actualExpression = expression.replace(",", " and").replace("||", "or")
```

which should give you new *valid expression* as

```
( (key == 999 and value == 55) or (key == 1234 and value == 12) )
```

Now that you have *valid expression*, your `dataframe` needs modification too as you can't query such expression on a column with `array` and `struct` as schema

So you would need `explode` function to *explode* the `array` elements to different rows and then use `.*` notation to select all the elements of `struct` on different columns.

```
val df1 = df.withColumn("metadata", explode($"metadata"))
  .select($"metadata.*")
```

which should give you `dataframe` as

```
+-----+-----+
|key  |value|
+-----+-----+
|84896|54   |
|1234 |12   |
+-----+-----+
```

And the finally use the *valid expression* on the `dataframe` generated as

```
df1.where(s"${actualExpression}")
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Answer (score 1):

First you should use `explode` to get an easy-to-work-with dataFrame. Then you can select both key and value of you given input:

```
val explodedDF = df.withColumn("metadata", explode($"metadata"))
  .select("metadata.key", "metadata.value")
```

Output:

```
+-----+-----+
|  key|value|
+-----+-----+
|84896|   54|
| 1234|   12|
+-----+-----+
```

This way you'll be able to perform your filtering logic as usual:

```
scala> explodedDF.where("key == 84896").show
+-----+-----+
|  key|value|
+-----+-----+
|84896|   54|
+-----+-----+
```

You can concatenate your filtering requirements, some examples below:

```
explodedDF.where("key == 84896 AND value == 54")
explodedDF.where("(key == 84896 AND value == 54) OR key = 1234")
```